# How to remove transformations from a matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I have a Transfromation matrix , which is combination of three other transformation matrixes.

```
glm::mat4 Matrix1 = position * rotation * scaling;
glm::mat4 Matrix2 = position * rotation * scaling;
glm::mat4 Matrix3 = position * rotation * scaling;  
glm::mat4 transMatrix = Matrix1 * Matrix2 * Matrix3;
```

if sometime later i just want to remove the effect of Matrix1 from the transMatrix.

How can i do that ?

Comment: probably inverse(Matrix1) * transMatrix

Comment: @Alex thank you , your answer works fine , if you would like to post this as an answer please do so.

Comment: if you want to extract (or reset) just position or rotation or scale then its doable directly see: [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) you just reset appropriate matrix cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you may simply multiply by the inverse of Matrix1:

```
glm::mat4 Matrix2And3 = glm::inverse(Matrix1) * transMatrix;
```

Order of operation is important, if you wanted to remove Matrix3, you would need make transMatrix * inverse(Matrix3) instead. If it was Matrix2, you would need to remove matrix1 (or 3) and then matrix2.

**However**, matrix inversion should be avoided at all costs, since it's very inefficient, and for your situation it is avoidable.

What you call Matrix is actually just a 3D Pose: Position + Rotation + Size.
Assuming you are using uniform scaling (Size = float) your mat3 component of your Pose, i.e., is a Orthogonal matrix, these type of matrices have a special property which is:

> Inverse(O) == Transpose(O)

Calculating the transpose of a matrix is a lot simpler than the inverse, this means that you can do the following, to achieve the same results but a lot **faster**:

```
mat4 inv = (mat4)transpose((mat3)Matrix1);
inv[3] = glm::vec4(-position1, 1.0f);
mat4 Matrix2And3 = inv * transMatrix;
```

If you want to go even further, I recommend you create Pose class and provide cast operators for mat4 and mat3, to take full performance at ease.